# Array list object to generic list of data row

Tags: vb.net

i have an array list which contains objects (obviously) . but actual type of the object when it was added was `"System.Collections.Generic.List(of system.Data.DataRow)"`
i am retrieving it back using following code  but the result contains **"zero"** number of rows.

```
 CustomerDetails = CType(in_TransactionItem(3),system.Collections.Generic.List(of system.Data.DataRow))
enter code here
```

in_transactionItem is an array list. 
position at 3 contains list of data rows. 
customerdetails is of the type **system.Collections.Generic.List(of system.Data.DataRow)**

any idea why `customerdetails.count` is zero!! and how to retrieve the list of data rows now?

*EDIT*
*peice of code which stores the datarow list into array list*

```
Dim PaymentDetailsRowList As New List(Of system.Data.DataRow)
Dim PaymentDetailsRowArray() As system.Data.DataRow =  PaymentDetailsTable.Select("TaxpayerID = '" + TransactionID + "'")
PaymentDetailsRowList = PaymentDetailsRowArray.ToList()
singlecustomerdata.Add(PaymentDetailsRowList)
 in_TransactionItem = singlecustomerdata
```

Comment: Can you please post the type of In_TransactionItem(3) . Also i think = is missing in the code you posted

Comment: just changed the  code little bit added some code. which will answer your query.

Comment: in_TransactionItem is an array . So we dont need to pass in_TransactionItem(3) to Ctype function

Comment: in_TransactionItem is an "ArrayList" , so it contains only object types . anything inside array list when we use "add" method will be stored in object format. we need to cast while we  pull it down. some time implicitly it happens some times explicitly we need to do . please correct me if am wrong.